# Динамическое заполнение базы данных

Tags: java, android

Имя таблицы ГОрода .
 в таблице есть столбец Улица .
У меня есть название улиц около 5 тысяч,
как мне это добавить улицы в базу данных ? 
метод   `values.put(DatabaseHelper.CİTY_STREET_COLUMN, "Улица гаршкофа н1");`
добавляет по одному , а у меня  улиц много , есть ли какойто способ более быстрый чем писать около 5 тысяч строк .

Наследую от Класса `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: А в чем проблема прочитать этот список улиц программно (из файла, или откуда где они у вас лежат) и вставить в таблицу?

Comment: Не проблемы как по сути нет просто у меня очень много файлов интересует способ добавления в столбцы динамически ,а не по одному

Comment: Я, к сожалению, никогда не работал с самой SQLite , но гугл показывает, что там есть возможность bulk insert'а: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Comment: Спасибо почитаю что там говорят